# Task 'assembleDevKernelDebug' not found in project ':app' - Android build using AppCenter

Tags: android, visual-studio-app-center

I have recently ejected my expo app using expo eject.

I have now tried to build using AppCenter, it gets about 4 minutes in and then fails with the following error message.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Task 'assembleDevKernelDebug' not found in project ':app'.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to fix this?

My android folder looks like this

[image]

My build.gradle looks like this

[image]